# How To Get Status Update Posted By Page - Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a desktop application in which I needs to grab `post_id` of only status updates posted by page itself (no photos, videos and other stories/types.) I'm using `type` parameter to do this task easily.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{username or ID of page}/posts?fields=object_id,type&limit=250&access_token={my access token}
```

The giving URL returning the list of posts with it's types and post ID

```
My Page Updated a Status
{
 "type": "status",
 "id": "493341197400693_627621933972618",
 "created_time": "2014-04-05T18:31:58+0000"
},
```

It's working fine but problem is some post in the list with the `type=status` are not a status update it's a story i.e `"My Page commented on a photo"`

```
My Page commented on a Photo
{
  "type": "status",
  "id": "493341197400693_626576670743811",
  "created_time": "2014-04-03T11:27:22+0000"
},
```

How to confirm that either it is a status update or a Story if the type of both response will be `"Status"`.
I just want to ignore `My Page commented on a photo` or `My Page Likes a Photo` etc, Any Suggestion?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look for the 'message' field. A status should have a 'message' field associated with it, whereas a story like 'My Page Likes a Photo' should not have a 'message'. Here is some sample php code.

```
if (array_key_exists("message", $post))
    //is a status
```

Modify you graph call to include message, like so.

https://graph.facebook.com/{username or ID of page}/posts?fields=object_id,type,message&limit=250&access_token={my access token}

Comment: hmmm so I needs add "message" parameter in graph url and then read each post one by one from the json response and if the "message" parameter is exists in posts data and also the type of post is equals to "status" then it's 100% a post which is made by page owner.
Acceptable answer it is.

Comment: exactly. glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the stream FQL table. You can use the field type to filter the posts to a finer level than it's possible with the Graph API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/#columns

Excerpt from the docs:

```
The type of this story. Possible values are:
11 - Group created
12 - Event created
46 - Status update
56 - Post on wall from another user
66 - Note created
80 - Link posted
128 -Video posted
247 - Photos posted
237 - App story
257 - Comment created
272 - App story
285 - Checkin to a place
308 - Post in Group
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm not familiar with FQL, but it's looking much easier then graph api, a single integer can tells the actual type of post.
Thank you Tobi I'll try FQL after finishing my current project.